# Web scraping when the item order appears to shuffle with pagination - indeed jobs

Tags: python, web-scraping, pagination

I'm attempting to record the information from the job site Indeed.com for all jobs resulting from a specific search term.
However, although when I search that term it says there are X jobs available (i.e., "showing Page 1 of X jobs"), the number of unique jobs (I remove  I record is much less. The number is also not consistent if I repeat the scraper and there are duplicates.
This makes me wonder if there is some shuffling of the contents (think sampling with replacement) so that there are unique jobs that I don't see.
Alternative could be that the number of jobs isn't correctly shown on the site. For example, [if you go to the last page](https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=sustainability&l=mi&sort=date&start=620) it's showing only approximately 620 jobs of the alleged 920. But this doesn't explain why I'm not getting consistently the same number of unique results if I run the code twice in quick succession.

Any thoughts?

The Python3 code is here if you want to run it.
Requires: requests, bs4, pandas, numpy

```
# modified from https://medium.com/@msalmon00/web-scraping-job-postings-from-indeed-96bd588dcb4b
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import time
import json
from html.parser import HTMLParser
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
import re
from itertools import chain

class MLStripper(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        self.reset()
        self.strict = False
        self.convert_charrefs= True
        self.fed = []
    def handle_data(self, d):
        self.fed.append(d)
    def get_data(self):
        return ''.join(self.fed)

def strip_tags(html):
    s = MLStripper()
    s.feed(html)
    result = s.get_data()
    # result = result.strip('\n')
    result = result.replace('\n',' ')
    return result

keyword = 'sustainability'
state = 'mi'
page_limit = 50

# init the dataframe
columns = ['job_code','keyword', 'job_title', 'company_name', 'location', 'salary']
jobs = []
div_list = []

# determine max number of results
page = requests.get('http://www.indeed.com/jobs?q={}&l={}'.format(keyword,state.lower()))
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
max_result_bs4 = soup.find(name='div', attrs = {'id':'searchCount'})#.find('directory').text
max_results = int(max_result_bs4.contents[0].split(' ')[-2].replace(',',''))

#scraping code:
# loop through pages
for start in chain(range(0, max_results, page_limit),range(0, max_results, page_limit)):
    url = 'https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q={}&start={}&limit={}&l={}&sort=date'.format(keyword, start, page_limit, state.lower())
    page = requests.get(url)
    time.sleep(0.01)  #ensuring at least 0.01 second between page grabs
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser', from_encoding='utf-8')
    # record the divs
    div_list += soup.find_all(name='div', attrs={'data-tn-component': 'organicJob'})
# format the scrapes
for div in div_list:
    #creating an empty list to hold the data for each posting
    job_post = []
    # get the job code
    job_code = div['data-jk']
    job_post.append(job_code)
    #append keyword name
    job_post.append(keyword)
    #grabbing job title
    for a in div.find_all(name='a', attrs={'data-tn-element':'jobTitle'}):
        title = a['title']
        if title:
            job_post.append(title)
        else:
            job_post.append('Not found')
    #grabbing company name
    company = div.find_all(name='span', attrs={'class':'company'})
    if len(company) > 0:
        for b in company:
            job_post.append(b.text.strip())
    else:
        sec_try = div.find_all(name='span', attrs={'class':'result-link-source'})
        for span in sec_try:
            job_post.append(span.text)
    if len(job_post) == 3:
        job_post.append('Not found')
    #grabbing location name
    job_post.append(state)
    #grabbing salary
    try:
        job_post.append(div.find('nobr').text)
    except:
        try:
            job_post.append(div.find(name='span', attrs={'class':'salary no-wrap'}).text.strip())
        except:
            job_post.append('Nothing_found')
    #appending list of job post info to dataframe at index num
    jobs.append(job_post)

df = pd.DataFrame(jobs, columns = columns)

#saving df as a local csv file — define your own local path to save contents
todays_date = datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d')
df.to_csv('indeed_{}.csv'.format(todays_date), encoding='utf-8')

df_len = len(df)
unique_jobs = len(np.unique(df.job_code))
print('Found {} unique jobs from an alleged {} after recording {} postings'.format(unique_jobs, max_results, df_len))
```

Comment: Why don't you just scrape it all, then create a unique list? I am sure there is some kind of unique code per job listing. Should be pretty easy and no need to worry about items shuffling around (it happens alot when you web scrape).

Comment: That's what I do and I filter by the unique code. But the number of unique values is not consistent if I repeat. I even did it twice and took only unique values and that's not complete.

Comment: Create a database, make a column that holds the unique code (make that column unique). Then everytime you scrape, you will only add in new items to the database. I would not try to get the same results on each scrape. Way to hard and probably won't happen. Why should always save your data somewhere to work with later.

Comment: ok - but I don't see how this will get all of the results from the website. other than making the column unique, I'm not seeing how this differs from my existing approach

Comment: You are not going to be able to get all results? The results are always changing? At least with the database, you have record of everything YOU scraped. That is about the best you can do. It is a dynamic website? People are controlling when a job goes up and down, etc.. Or maybe I am not understanding your end goal here?

Comment: interesting. do you think that the results will consistently be changing within a minute ?

Comment: Yeah for sure. They serve content based on many reason. Plus by you recording the data yourself, you can see if your missing anything, that you can see on the site.